# Golang with Qt issue with painting in paintEvent

Tags: qt, go

I'm using this Golang Qt binding [here](https://github.com/therecipe/qt) to create a simple code editor. I'm connecting a `paintEvent` callback handler to the actual editor, in which I'm trying to do the painting. As I've found in various forums this is the only point when the painting should be done. 
However, when calling `painter := gui.NewQPainter2(ce.editor)` I receive some warning outputs

```
QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
```

and when calling the `setPen` function I get the message

QPainter::setPen: Painter not active

Here is a working example of the issue

```
package main


import (
    "os"

    "github.com/therecipe/qt/widgets"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/gui"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/core"
)

type CodeEditor struct {
    editor *widgets.QPlainTextEdit
}

func NewCodeEditor(parent *widgets.QWidget) *CodeEditor {
    codeEditor := &CodeEditor{editor: widgets.NewQPlainTextEdit(parent)}
    codeEditor.setupSignals()
    return codeEditor
}

func (ce *CodeEditor) setupSignals() {
    ce.editor.ConnectPaintEvent(ce.paintEvent)
}

func (ce *CodeEditor) paintEvent(event *gui.QPaintEvent) {
    painter := gui.NewQPainter2(ce.editor)
    color := gui.NewQColor6("red")
    painter.SetPen2(color)
    painter.DestroyQPainter()
}

func main() {
    core.QCoreApplication_SetAttribute(core.Qt__AA_ShareOpenGLContexts, true)
    widgets.NewQApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args)

    mainWindow := widgets.NewQMainWindow(nil, 0)
    codeEditor := NewCodeEditor(nil)

    mainWindow.SetCentralWidget(codeEditor.editor)
    mainWindow.ShowMaximized()

    widgets.QApplication_Exec()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not activated the QPainter instance.
Check https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#begin

Comment: The `NewQPainter2` will do that automatically, so there's no need for an explicit `begin(...)`; but just to double check I've tried including it and I still have the same problem